# Gamemaker: Making a bullet Spawn at the enemy it was called from

Tags: game-maker

I'm making a gamemaker game with gml. In this game I have multiple enemies (same object) on screen at the same time. I want them to all spawn a bullet at their location. But instead each enemy spawns a bullet at one single enemy. They all shoot but the bullets appear in the wrong location. I want the bullet to spawn at the location of the instance is was called for. How do I do this?

Thank you for reading my question.

Code:
obj_carrier is the enemy I want to spawn from.
obj_carrier_bullet is the bullet I want to spawn at location of the carrier
There are multiple carriers around the stage.
In the step event of the carrier following an if statement:

```
   instance_create(obj_carrier.x, obj_carrier.y, obj_carrier_bullet)
```

Comment: Please post your code, we can only guess at the issue without it.

Comment: Here you go. :)

Comment: Where are you getting your object coordinates from? Try adding some additional code, as this function call alone doesn't provide much context. At the moment, I would say you are not getting unique object coordinates, and simply referencing the same carrier object every time.

Comment: If you are creating obj_carrier_bullet from obj_carrier (ie in its step event, or alarm event, or wherever), just use x and y. obj_carrier.x will create it on the first obj_carrier's x position.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating/spawning the bullet from within the obj_carrier that is to create the bullet (ie inside its step event, or alarm event, etc), you can just use x and y:

```
instance_create(x, y, obj_carrier_bullet);
```

If you are creating it from a different object, you will have to figure out which object it is and create it from there (ie:

```
var objectThatWillCreateBullet = instance_create(random(room_width), random(room_height), obj_carrier);
instance_create(objectThatWillCreateBullet.x, objectThatWillCreateBullet.y, obj_carrier_bullet);
```

This is probably not what you are doing though).

If you want all obj_carrier's to create a bullet at once, you can do:

```
with(obj_carrier) {
    instance_create(x,y,obj_carrier_bullet);
}
```